# vb.net: How can I see if the value of an element is in a list

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, list

In vb.net, I can do:

```
Select Case value
   Case "2", "4", "6"
     Foo()

   Case "1", "3", "5"
     Bar()

End Select
```

Now I find myself needing to do both Foo() and Bar() if value is "7" - is there a simple way to do this with an If condition?

Something like

```
if ("2","4","6","7").contains(value) then
   Foo()
end if

if ("1","3","5","7").contains(value) then
   Bar()
end if
```

I don't want to have to declare & initialize two lists if I can avoid it.

Edit:  I should have mentioned that this is a simplified example - there are actually a dozen or so `CASE` statements, and Foo() and Bar() are actually placeholders for quite a bit more code - it's seeing the same block of code repeated over and over that got me thinking about a better way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

I think you were already on the right track with the Case statement.  Give this a try:

```
Select Case value 
   Case "2", "4", "6" 
     Foo() 

   Case "1", "3", "5" 
     Bar() 

   Case "7"
     Foo()
     Bar()

End Select
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add an extra case for 7 which calls both Foo and Bar? That seems to be the simplest way of communicating what will happen for any particular value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Case "7"
  Foo()
  Bar()
```